# Convert an interval variable to ordinal in SPSS

Tags: spss, probit

I am currently conducting a study on reverse mortgages for my master thesis, and I'd like to convert one interval variable into ordinal in order to run a ordinal probit regression analysis.

My interval variable is: "A reverse mortgage is generally a good deal" --> 1-7 Likert scale (where 1 = totally disagree, 4 =neutral, 7 = totally agree).

How can I how transform this variable?

Comment: Likert items are ordinal, not interval. A scale constructed from multiple Likert items becomes interval by assuming the ordinal components are interval (rendering the scale items able to be added).

Comment: It is you, who decides whether a likert-type rating scale is interval (the liberal decision) or ordinal (the conservative decision). Note also, that ordinal means "unknown true distances between the scale grades". So, because in interval scale you know them, converting interval to ordinal implies amnesia.

Comment: @Glen_b Correct, naturally, but OP seems to want to go the other way.

Comment: Andrea - if you want to treat something as ordinal, you just need to treat the values as ordered categories instead of as values. You don't necessarily need to change the data values themselves.

Comment: For completeness, if you are estimating this using say the `PLUM` command, you don't need to convert the variable to anything in SPSS. If you are using `GENLIN` or `GENLINMIXED`, the variable *level* likely needs to be specified as ordinal. An example would be `VARIABLE LEVEL YourVar (ORDINAL).`

Comment: @ttnphns: "It is you, who decides whether a likert-type rating scale **is** interval". I disagree, it **is** ordinal. Period. However, you may decide to **treat it as interval** which is called making the [assumption of equal intervals](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/assumption-of-equal-intervals/).

Comment: @Ruben, let us not start philosophical/linguistic discussions. For me, a thing can be "this and not that" but due to the decision of my consciousness. Period. Any _specific_ being is thus an assumption.

Comment: @ttnphns: I insist it's an important distinction. Not making it is adding to the confusion about the nature of measurement levels, making some believe you can turn ordinal variables into interval. "Philosophical discussions" are often useful and sometimes even necessary to clarify what we're *really* talking about.

Comment: @Ruben, nope. Logical erratum. If I arbitrarily declare "It is A, not B" it doesn't mean I can "turn" A into B, i.e. `A->B`. I can re-decide, which implies `A->nothing->B`, which is different.

Answer (score 1):

This is unclear.

1. If your variable is on a 1(1)7 scale already, then it's ordinal already; how you tell SPSS that is a detail beyond the scope of this site. See the Help Center for advice on software-related questions.
2. If your variable is currently in some other form, then you need to explain what that form is to get advice on how to convert.

I find it hard to imagine how a variable answering the question "A reverse mortgage is generally a good deal" can be on an interval scale, but that's what you need to explain.